# Using CreateGraphics in Processing with Methods to output multipage PDF

Tags: java, pdf, processing

I have a class that I want to use to output pages to a pdf 
Each instance of the `foo` class will be a separate page
(N.B page/output size is not the same as the screen)

How do I use the custom method `display()` to print to each page? 
or have I got it all wrong?

```
class foo{

int fooWidth, fooHeight;
ArrayList<goo> gooList;


foo(){
//constructors etc
}

void display(){
//display stuff
//calls nested goo objects in Arraylist and displays them too
}

void output(){
PGraphics pdf = createGraphics(fooWidth, fooHeight, PDF, "foo.pdf");
pdf.beginDraw();

///display() code here

pdf.dispose();
pdf.endDraw();

}//foo class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you probably don't want to call `createGraphics()` from inside your `Foo` (classes should start with an upper-case letter) class, unless you want a separate PDF file for each instance!

Instead, use an instance of the `PGraphicsPDF` class from your sketch's `draw()` function, and then simply pass that instance into each instance of `Foo`. It might look something like this:

```
ArrayList<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();

void setup() {
  size(400, 400, PDF, "filename.pdf");
  //populate fooList
}

void draw() {

  PGraphicsPDF pdf = (PGraphicsPDF) g;  // Get the renderer

  for(Foo foo : fooList){
    foo.display(pdf); //draw the Foo to the PDF
    pdf.nextPage();  // Tell it to go to the next page
  }
}
```

(code based off the reference on [this](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/pdf/) page)

And then your `Foo` class just needs a `display()` function that takes `PGraphicsPDF` as an argument:

```
class Foo{
   public void display(PGraphicsPDF pdf){
      pdf.ellipse(25, 25, 50, 50);
      //whatever
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey Kevin
Thanks for answering! You are totally right about `foo` needing to be `Foo`… Passing the `PGraphicsPDF` as an argument is a good solution, I would then pass it down to the nested objects. I think that I need to think about what I want out of the other end a little bit more before I decide whether or not to make a separate pdf for each instance of `Foo` – both have advantages for me. In the real code a `Foo` would be a page anyway, so it would possibly make sense.